# How to get a output of a hidden layer of a single-layer LSTM

Tags: deep-learning, keras, r, lstm, rstudio

How can get the hidden layer outputs in a simple one-layer lstm?

```
cat("Building Model\n")                                                

model <- keras_model_sequential() %>% 
  layer_lstm(units = 64, dropout = 0.2, input_shape = c(seqlength, length(chars))) %>% 
  layer_dense(units = length(chars), activation = "softmax") %>% 


  compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',
          optimizer = optimizer_sgd(lr = 0.001,
                                    decay = 1e-6,
                                    momentum = 0.9,
                                    nesterov = T),
          metrics = c('accuracy'))

summary(model)


cat("Training \n")                                                

history <- model %>%
  fit(train,
      trainLabels,
      epochs = 6,
      batch_size = 16,
      validation_split = 0.2)
```

I found this guid but I don't know how to fit it to this simple model and what is data.

```
model <- ...  # create the original model

layer_name <- 'my_layer' intermediate_layer_model <- keras_model(inputs = 
                  model$input,outputs = get_layer(model, layer_name)$output) 
intermediate_output <- predict(intermediate_layer_model, data)
```

Can anybody give a sample of this?

Answer (score 0):

You'll definitely want to name the layer you want to observe first (otherwise you'll be doing guesswork with the sequentially generated layer names):

```r
model <- keras_model_sequential() %>% 
  layer_lstm(units = 64, 
             dropout = 0.2, 
             input_shape = c(seqlength, length(chars)),
             name = "lstm") %>% 
  ...
```

The rest is pretty straightforward:

```r
lstm_layer_model <- keras_model(
  inputs = model$input, 
  outputs = get_layer(model, "lstm")$output
) 
lstm_output <- predict(lstm_layer_model, new_data)
```

So if you want to know the LSTM neuron values for a given case, define that case's features as `new_data` and run the last line.

Answer (score 0):

In TensorFlow for R there is a `return_state` parameter for the `layer_lstm` object ([documentation](https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/reference/keras/layer_lstm)). Setting it to True will make the object return the hidden states of the lstm.

I'm not well versed enough in R to give a bug-free code-snippet without testing, but I'm sure you can figure it out with the documentation.